# Opencart ajax checkout

Tags: ajax, opencart

403 Forbidden
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
How to fix this problem. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have permission to the  controller that ajax call are trying to access.

Go To Admin Panel -> Admins -> Admin Groups

and edit your admin permissions.That may help you.